# Is there a #pragma mark (objective c) equivalent in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I tried searching for this, but all I could land up with is `#region`.

This helps in traversing through the class, but the method pop up menu does not show the tag.

Is there anyway we can list specific methods under a heading in method pop up of a class in visual studio?

**EDIT 1:** 
In x-code suppose I have 10 methods (methods 1, method 2, method 3...method 10). 
When I write #pragma mark - `XYZ` before method 1, & then #pragma mark - `FOO` before method 8 the method pop up groups methods 1 to 7 under `XYZ` & then methods 8 to 10 under `FOO`.

This makes traversing through the class easier. Also its much easier to maintain.

Does visual studio have anything similar?

**EDIT 2:**

Added image. Thus in the image `Initialization`, `Table Management` & `Managing Views` form a group and are put under a similar `#pragma mark`.

[image]

Comment: I think you can do this with the ///<summary> syntax. Although I am not entirely sure what you mean. Something like having a description that aprears when hovering over and selecting a method with intellisense?

Comment: Added EDIT 1: Hope I was clear!!

Comment: Ohhh I see what you are asking yea the closest thing to what you are asking is `#region` which will allow you to group methods similar to `#pragma mark`, I believe you can also use the `///<summary>` syntax above the region and it should give you information in the same way as a method would.

Comment: Added image of the method pop up in x-code. This shows the methods present in the class.

Comment: Hmmm i think the closest thing to what you have there is in VS when you open the solution explorer or Object browser you can expand a class and it looks kind of like that. However I do not think there is a one-to-one copy of that in VS.

Comment: VS has "#region RegionName" but the only outline you can get of the class is by collapsing all regions to show only the top level region names.

Comment: Use `#region` with interfaces e.g. `IInitialization, ICleanup, ITableManagement, etc`. In VS2012 the Solution Explorer will organize the class like in your picture -- unfortunately, VS2010 doesn't have the same feature.

Comment: The OP is not talking about organizing the class - the OP is talking about the dropdown menu (the one that is right and above the editor window). In Xcode, we have the ability to add user defined strings that also insert bars - it helps visually break up the code into sections. It also makes it far easier to go to the correct method. #region does not appear to perform this action in VS2012.

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: @AlexDelgado am using #region & #endregion!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hitting 3 `/` on the line before the method?  that typically auto-inserts syntax to describe a method that appears in the mouse-over popup.

Comment: Added image for more clarity of what I was talking about.

Comment: You can right-click a class in the solution explorer and do View Class Diagram to get something similar to what you posted

Comment: You can also use the dropdowns above the text editor to give you shortcuts to whatever you're looking for

Comment: I'm not sure you are understanding what the problem is. What the OP is asking is if there is a way to insert a user generated string in the drop down menu of functions (top right above the main editor window). This user string is bolded and makes it easier to arrange code (and get to the correct method). The OP is not asking about auto-inserts, class diagrams, etc. To clarify, imagine that the drop down menu of methods looks like the image the OP shared. That is what the person is looking for. I know, because I'm looking for it as well.

Comment: when I answered the question was different.  Look at the OP time, it's edit time and my answer time.  Maybe I should delete it if its not relevant anymore.

Comment: The original question was the same, just not as clear.